# Is there a difference between utf-8 and normal text length storage in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

If save two `utf-8` and normal text(only English character) in text field
is there a difference between storage length in database(maybe convert not English character to English character)?

Example:
if i save `ali` word in database, save as : `ali`
but if i save `علی` word in database, save as : some code more than 3 char

Database: MySQL
Engine : InnoDB

Comment: Yes. It's the difference between the LENGTH of the string (in bytes) and the CHAR_LENGTH of the string (characters). 'Normal' characters are 1 byte but multibyte characters occupy, well, multiple bytes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of `UTF-8` is that various Unicode characters are encoded using byte sequences of different lengths:

- Basic Latin letters, digits, and punctuation signs use **one byte**.
- Most European and Middle East script letters fit into a **2-byte** sequence: extended Latin letters (with tilde, macron, acute, grave and other accents), Cyrillic, Greek, Armenian, Hebrew, Arabic, Syriac, and others.
- Korean, Chinese, and Japanese ideographs use **3-bytes** sequences.

**Tip:** To save space with UTF-8, use `VARCHAR` instead of `CHAR`. Otherwise, MySQL must reserve **three bytes** for each character in a `CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8 column` because that is the maximum possible length. For example, MySQL must reserve 30 bytes for a CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 column.